# Compressor Questions and Making a 5.1 Mix with 95% in Stereo?

Tags: effects, stereo, mix, 5.1

I've been editing videos for a few years now and have always done my sound editing in Final Cut Pro (7).. But with this new big documentary project I'm working on, I'm hoping to make Soundtrack Pro my new application of choice for making the audio the best I can make it with the resources that I have available. I've got a few (newbie) questions though that I would love to hear some insight on if you have the time and are able to help! I'm not expecting long answers so you can absolutely keep things short and simple if you decide to chime in.. My questions are

1) Are there are any effects that I should make sure to apply to every audio clip? Bringing the audio into Soundtrack feels like a step in the right direction but I've never used the effect of "Compressor" before on the audio.. and since this is a feature film I'm really wanting to step up my game as far as applying what I need to apply.. Expanders will be used on some tracks, and some Limiters.. But should Compressor be applied to each track as well? Or would applying a Compressor to the Submix be an alright way to go?

2) Since this is a documentary and not a story with sound effects and the like, I'm hoping to edit the film in stereo. But at the same time there are certain markets (like iTunes) who will only accept films for release in their store that have 5.1 audio. This makes me think that I should edit the film in 5.1 and just keep things stereo for the most part. Could I edit in 5.1 and not even utilize the Left Surround, Right Surround and LFE and have it still be exported as a 5.1 mix even when there is nothing in those channels? Or would one basic sound in each of those channels at a certain point in the movie suffice to make the audio export correctly at 5.1?

Comment: If you want to ask multiple questions, please ask multiple questions.  Each question may have a distinct answer and may be answerable by different people.  Additionally, bundling questions makes it difficult for others to find the answers they need in the future as it makes the question harder to find.